# I want help translating this article

Tags: reference-request

I can find someone who masters the Russian language

I want help translating this article :

[image]

Comment: I'll help a little with the title. "Extremal problems with respect to convergence in measure for convex functionals semicontinuous from the below."

Comment: Something like this.)

Comment: I'm not sure this question meets the guidelines in the Help Center. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @kolobokish Yes, I understood the address and I already looked for it, but I did not find it in English.

Can you help me

Comment: Nearly all of the better known Russian mathematics journals (since around the early 1960s) have corresponding English translation journal versions. If you can give some bibliographic information about this paper (or at least provide the [MR](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup) or [Zbl](https://zbmath.org/) citation, which will provide the journal name), then maybe someone can point you to an already published translation.

Answer (score 2):

An English translation already exists. This article is listed in MathSciNet as https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=390880 The articles in Doklady are often translated into English then, and indeed the article appears in English in

Soviet Math. Dokl. 15 (1975), no. 5, 1384–1388 (1976)

(You will need to trek down to your nearest academic library for this, though; if memory serves the Soviet Math. Dokl. volumes from before 1980 are not digitised.)

Comment: Incidentally, same info is listed on the author's own webpage: http://mathecon.cemi.rssi.ru/en/vlevin/publications.htm , though there it states that it is volume 16 (and not 15) of the Soviet Math. Dokl. So check both volumes; if it is in volume 16, you can send an erratum to MathSciNet.

Comment: I thought it looked like a Soviet Math. Doklady paper (I have photocopies of several dozen of them, mostly involving [cluster set theory](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cluster+set%22+%22Doklady+Akademii%22+%22function%22&filter=0) before 1990), but I thought it best not to speculate in my comment to the OP.

Comment: you can download this article for me if you want.